# How to get files for current date only when picking all files that match a given Pattern

Tags: java, regex, unix, operating-system, java-7

```
public static List<String> getLogFiles(String logLocation, final String pattern) {
    File logDirectory = new File(logLocation);
    String[] files = new String[]{};            
    if (logDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        files = logDirectory.list(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.matches(pattern);
            }

        });
    }


    return Arrays.asList(files);
}
```

If I pass `/tmp/logs` and a regex for `*.log` in above snippet, I get all logs files for all dates, but I want the result to get trimmed down to today's date files only. Can I get this done with Java 7 after I get the whole list above, or is there a better way altogether?

I will run this on Unix box with jdk 1.7_71 64 bit JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use File.lasModified method to compare file date modification, try this code:

```
public static List<String> getLogFiles(String logLocation, final String pattern, String date) throws ParseException
{
   File logDirectory = new File(logLocation);
   String[] files = new String[] {};

   SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
   Date d = f.parse(date);
   long milliseconds = d.getTime();

   if (logDirectory.isDirectory())
   {
     files = logDirectory.list(new FilenameFilter()
     {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
            return name.matches(pattern) && new File(dir, name).lastModified() > milliseconds;
        }
    });
  }
  return Arrays.asList(files);
}
```

Comment: Works well for me thnx Naruto

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons-io library which provides predefined filters and supports filter chaining.

```
AgeFileFilter ageFilter = new AgeFileFilter(milliseconds, false);    
WildcardFileFilter wildcardFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(pattern);    
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(logDirectory, new AndFileFilter(ageFilter, wildcardFilter), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
```

Note that it returns collection of file objects instead array of Strings.